# Set to true navigator.cookieEnabled if is false in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cookies, navigator

I have a page that includes a third party iframe.
I cannot access iframe if cookies are not allowed in the browser.
Can **navigator.cookieEnabled** be set if **false** to **true** with javascript?

I tried with the browser bloking all the cookies and don't wana set me in **true** the
**navigator.cookieEnabled**.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set `navigator.cookieEnabled` to true as it is readonly per documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/cookieEnabled